# When creating a new dictionary key in Python, are there benefits to creating it with `update` rather than simply =?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's assume I am making a key-value pair that will not consist of any subkeys.

`self.profiles[server.id][author.id]['games']['accounts']['league']` already exists. Is there any benefit or purpose of using

`self.profiles[server.id][author.id]['games']['accounts']['league'].update({'plays': true})`

over

`self.profiles[server.id][author.id]['games']['accounts']['league']['plays'] = True`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.update` with only a single key changing is going to be significantly less efficient.

A simple benchmark on my desktop

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'd={}' 'd.update({"x":3})'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.263 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'd={}' 'd["x"]=3'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0409 usec per loop
```

This is because to update the key with `.update`, it requires creating a new dictionary and then iterating over all the keys in the dictionary (even though there's only one). Plus there is always an overhead with function calls in Python.

Comment: While the timeit analysis is great a simple analysis with `dis` shows that there is no iteration penalty in the example you provide. The big difference is actually constructing the dict, and then the update call.

Comment: Nit: [C]Python turns programs into internal bytecode prior to execution. Only environments like 'bash' or 'PowerShell' are really "interpreted" these days..

Comment: @MatthewStory If you look at the bytecode, you'll see it calls the `.update` function. The `dis` output won't include the bytecode for this function, but you will certainly have to iterate over the dictionary in some way.

Comment: @user2864740 Entirely depends on what you're using to execute your Python code, but fair point :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case no, using the set item syntax is preferred.

But if you have multiple pairs you want to add to a dict, that's where update shines:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2}

new_pairs = {'c':3, 'd':4}

d.update(new_pairs)  

print(d)   # d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
```

This will also change the values for keys that are both in `d` and `new_pairs` (to the value of `new_pairs[k]`):

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':"before"}

new_pairs = {'b':"after", 'c':3, 'd':4}

d.update(new_pairs)

print(d)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 'after', 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```